# feed data into a UI through multiple services

Tags: web-services, user-interface

Is there a  way where I can create a UI that takes data from multiple web services? For eg when an event happens, it calls an event handler (implemented on one of the service's side) and the service sends an update to the UI.
Also the design needs to be modular in the sense that if I need to add a new service to feed data to the UI, all I need to do is writer some event handlers on the service's side.

Is there a solution for this problem?

I found something like this: http://www.w3.org/TR/xup/ (Extensible User Interface Protocol)
[image]

But didn't find a concrete implementation.

Comment: Yes there is a solution for this problem however you are not showing us any code. Cant help unless the problem is more concrete and less abstract.

Comment: @Namphibian I have no code right now cause I have not started yet. Can't start implementing without knowing the answer to this question.